# Using legacy mysql database with new sails application

Tags: mysql, sails.js, sails-mongo, sails-postgresql

When setting up sails models to use an existing MySql database with string primary keys (PK), the PK is no longer generated automatically.
Am I missing something or do I have to implement the PK generation in `beforeCreate`? If I were to implement the PK generation, I'm not sure how to avoid having key collisions with the existing keys from the legacy db.

Calling `Cat.create().exec(console.log)` throws the following error:

```
Invalid attributes sent to User:
• id
  • `undefined` should be a string (instead of "null", which is a object)
  • "required" validation rule failed for input: null
```

The model has the following code:

```
module.exports = {
connection: 'laraschMysql',
schema: true,
identity: 'Contest',
tableName: 'Contest',
migrate: 'safe',
autoPK: false,
autoCreatedAt: false,
autoUpdatedAt: false,
autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'string',     //varchar(255) in the db                                                                       
      autoIncrement:true, // not working?
      primaryKey: true,
      required: true
    }
}
```

Put more generally: What are the usual problems / stumbling blocks / issues when using a legacy database with a new sails application?

Are there any good guides ( the sails documentation doesn't seem to cover the subject too thoroughly ) to setting up a legacy db with sails?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sails.js documentation autoIncrement must always be type: 'integer'

> autoIncrement
>
> Sets up the attribute as an auto-increment key. When a new record is
>   added to the model, if a value for this attribute is not specified, it
>   will be generated by incrementing the most recent record's value by
>   one. Note: Attributes which specify autoIncrement should always be of
>   type: 'integer'. Also, bear in mind that the level of support varies
>   across different datastores. For instance, MySQL will not allow more
>   than one auto-incrementing column per table.